# Update a increasing value by MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL, data like this:

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------+-------+
| address   | subnet_id                            | major |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+-------+
| 2.2.2.2   | 7ec1f191-476d-46cd-8fc9-0a8d24dfb8e9 |     0 |
| 7.7.7.7   | 7ec1f191-476d-46cd-8fc9-0a8d24dfb8e9 |     0 |
| 1.1.1.1   | 7ec1f191-476d-46cd-8fc9-0a8d24dfb8e9 |     0 |
| 3.3.3.3   | 7ec1f191-476d-46cd-8fc9-0a8d24dfb8e9 |     0 |
| 4.4.4.4   | 7ec1f191-476d-46cd-8fc9-0a8d24dfb8e9 |     0 |
| 9.99.9.10 | 7ec1f191-476d-46cd-8fc9-0a8d24dfb8e9 |     0 |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+-------+
```

I need to update `major` column to a increasing number (from 0 to 1, 2, 3...) . For a example, update subnet_id equals'7ec1f191-476d-46cd-8fc9-0a8d24dfb8e9'. The result should be like this:

```
+-----------+--------------------------------------+-------+
| address   | subnet_id                            | major |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+-------+
| 2.2.2.2   | 7ec1f191-476d-46cd-8fc9-0a8d24dfb8e9 |     0 |
| 7.7.7.7   | 7ec1f191-476d-46cd-8fc9-0a8d24dfb8e9 |     1 |
| 1.1.1.1   | 7ec1f191-476d-46cd-8fc9-0a8d24dfb8e9 |     2 |
| 3.3.3.3   | 7ec1f191-476d-46cd-8fc9-0a8d24dfb8e9 |     3 |
| 4.4.4.4   | 7ec1f191-476d-46cd-8fc9-0a8d24dfb8e9 |     4 |
| 9.99.9.10 | 7ec1f191-476d-46cd-8fc9-0a8d24dfb8e9 |     5 |
+-----------+--------------------------------------+-------+
```

What should I do by `MYSQL`?

Comment: For me it's difficult to understand what you want to achieve, can you explain better what kind of update do you want to do and explain better the mechanics of your table?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look at it again. :-)

Comment: @changzh, for each different `subnet_id`, do you need  increasing number again from 0 ?

Comment: Yes @OTARIKI, there are different subnet_id in this table. I need to update all of them.

Comment: Is there a specific ordering you want? For example why do address 7.7.7.7 have major 1 and address 1.1.1.1 major 2?

Comment: Just a increasing number is okay. In the same subnet_id, every 'address' should have a increasing number in 'major' column. @Lennart

Answer (score 2):

To get your desired output you can use rank query in update using user defined variables, to have a correct ordering i assume every combination of `address,subnet_id` is unique

```
update table1 t1 
join (
select address,subnet_id,
@r:= case when @g = subnet_id then @r +1 else 0 end rownum,
@g:= subnet_id
from table1
cross join (select @r:= 0 , @g:=null) vars
order by subnet_id
 ) t2 using(address,subnet_id)
 set major = t2.rownum
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67ca4/1)

Comment: This assumes that subnets are ordered together, but there is nothing in the update that guarantees that. It may (or may not, not sure if anything guarantees it) help to add `order by subnet_id` in t2. I modified your fiddle at: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9f07/1

Comment: @Lennart yup you are right to have a correct sequence no. for each subnet order by is needed thanks for correction